# Get posts with multiple tags via junction table (many-to-many)

Tags: php, mysql, tags, many-to-many, posts

At the moment the function "*getPostTag*" returns only one tag. 
I've created a junction table with a "*post_id*" foreign key to a table called "*posts*" and 
a "*tag_id*" foreign key to a table called "*tags*" where those entries are stored accordingly.
With this table I want it to be able to attach multiple tags to multiple posts.
Then it also should be able to return each post with its set of tags.

How can I achieve this? (I wouldn't be disappointed if these functions need to be completely reworked.)

```
function getPosts() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $final_posts = array();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $post['tag'] = getPostTag($post['id']); 
        array_push($final_posts, $post);
    }
    return $final_posts;
}
```

```
function getPostTag($post_id){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id=
            (SELECT tag_id FROM post_tags WHERE post_id=$post_id) LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $tag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to return these tags? Do you want `$post['tag']` to be an array of tags?

Comment: Ok, thx. I really don't know, actually. I just thought this would be efficient. As you can see I'm a total SQL Noob. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function `getPostTag()` into `getPostTags()` which will return an array of tags. Use `mysqli_fetch_all()` same as in your other function. The SQL, in my opinion, should be using JOINs instead of subqueries.

You should stay away from globals. Pass arguments to functions instead.

I would propose to change your functions this way:

```
function getPosts(mysqli $conn): ?array {
    $posts = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    foreach ($posts as $id => $post) {
        $posts[$id]['tag'] = getPostTags($conn, $post['id']);
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

```
function getPostTags(mysqli $conn, int $post_id): ?array {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
        FROM tags 
        JOIN post_tags ON tags.id = post_tags.tag_id
        WHERE post_id=?");
    // binding as an integer since we know the type
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $post_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

I do not recommend using `SELECT *`. You should list all the columns that you need to fetch. Don't fetch everything, as this could lead to a messy and buggy code.